# User input to an arraylist in c++

Tags: c++

I need to put a user input into a array set to 10. So the user can put only
one value if he want but he can also go up to 10. how can I do that?

the user can choose a value that will be added to an array list. I want him/her to be able to come back to test() and additional value without overwriting the first one.

```
void test123();
int main() {
    int choice = 0;
    bool end = false;
    while (!end) {
        menu::menuMain();
        std::cout << "\n choose " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
    case 0:
    std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
      end = true;
      break;
    
    case 1:
      test();
      break;
       }

    void test() {
      int array[10];
      int value1;
    
      std::cout << " enter a value" << std::endl;
      std::cin >> value1;
    
      int value2 = value1 * 7; //I want value2 to go in array.
    
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //??????????
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted is not valid, as it won't compile. First you should determine what you want the user to see when interacting with the program. Some possibilities: 1. Ask the user to enter the number of entries, and then the entries one per line. 2. Ask the user to enter the numbers on one line, separated by spaces (or commas, or whatever), 3. Ask the user to keep entering numbers one per line, or enter a non-number in order to quit. Do you have a preference?

Comment: Note: `void test();` is a function declaration. It tells the compiler that the `test` function exists and doesn't do anything else. If you mean to call the `test` function, you want `test();`

Comment: Note: `int * array[10];` makes an array of 10 pointers to integers. These pointers currently have nothing to point at, so attempting to use these pointers is likely going to be fatal. You probably do not want pointers here at all, `int array[10];` provides an array of ten `int`s, but to give any concrete solutions we need more information.

Comment: What's your experience level with programming in general? Do you have access to a professor or teaching staff you can ask?

Comment: I know it dosent compile its just an exemple to show what i want to do.

Comment: user4581301  ty.

Comment: Suggestion: It looks like you're trying to write the whole program and then test. This almost always leads to wasted time. Test early and test often. Write a few lines of code, just enough to accomplish one easily testable thing. Compile the program. Test the <expletive deleted> out of the program to ensure you get the required behaviour and nothing else. Once everything checks out, write a few more lines and repeat.

Comment: This sounds slow, but is almost always faster than letting mistakes build up, having to untangle and solve each mistake, and often have to rewrite whole swaths of code that were based on early mistakes and are not viable after the early mistakes are corrected.

Comment: user4581301  not the case at all here but ty anyway.

Comment: All i want to do is add an input from a user. The user can add another input and it shall not overwrite the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static counter in the function

```
void test() {
  static int array[10];
  int value1;

  std::cout << " enter a value" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> value1;

  int value2 = value1 * 7; //I want value2 to go in array.

  static unsigned int i = 0;
  if (i >= 10) throw "More than 10 values";
  array[i] = value2;
  ++i;

  // do something with the array
}
```

Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>

void test() {
  static int array[10];
  int value1;

  std::cout << " enter a value" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> value1;

  int value2 = value1 * 7; //I want value2 to go in array.

  static unsigned int i = 0;
  if (i >= 10) throw "More than 10 values";
  array[i] = value2;
  ++i;

  // do something with the array
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
    std::cout << array[j] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  test();
  test();
  test();
  test();
  test();
}
```

Comment: thx alot that is what i was looking for !!